# Skype GUI messed up - Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and Skype 4.3

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, skype

My Skype GUI is completely messed up (elements invisible, above each other or other artefacts).

This is true for all Skype windows (main, chat, pop up window when being called). Some items will suddenly show when I move my mouse over them.

Items (e.g. a button to accept a call) are click-able, if you know where they are.

I found [this bug-report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/46309) on Arch, but that doesn't work for me (usually, a reboot doesn't help either).

```
System: Mint 17.2 (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) 64-bit
Cinnamon: 2.8.4
Skype: 4.3.0.37
X.Org: X.Org X Server 1.15.1

Graphics card (onboard): VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4290]
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem before you can simply edit skype.desktop

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

then change:

```
Exec=skype %U
```

to

```
Exec=env "QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" skype %U
```

reference from [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)